# tables mysql and c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on a database in MySQL (phpmyadmin), after connecting to the database in C#, I made a class to represent an alarm.

Then, I clustered alarms into groups (each alarm has a cid). My clusters are in a Set (I defined clusters as a List).

Now, I want to show each cluster's alarms in a table but I don't know if it is better to write and create a table in MySQL or to define a dataset in C#.

Here is my code so far:

```
foreach (cluster c in set)
{
    foreach (alarm a in c.mycluster)
    {
    }
}
```

The number of the clusters which will be generated depends on my input.

1. Which version is better? Getting a dataset in C# and showing them in a Windows Forms application or MySQL commands in C# creating table and views?
2. If any one of them is recommend, how can I do it? Some pseudo code would be enough to get me started.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

> 1.which one in your idea is better?getting a dataset in C# and showing them in a Form application or mysql commands in C# creating table and
>   views?

Since this is typically a presentation matter, I would do it in C# and not in mysql.
You do not want to create views or tables in the database for every way you  want to present the data. Also, if your presentation-demands change, you would need to change the database. So go for c#. There are plenty of tutorials around on how to do it.

Comment: yes exactly I want to present the data but you know what? in the mysql-phpmyadmin I can sort the alarms by each feature is it possible in dataset too?

Comment: yes, just fill the dataset with a sql query that already performs the sort while fetching the data. Sorting is typically better in the DB